# Alternative to writing the same code before the loop

Tags: c, arrays

I want to make the for loop execute the code in the beginning. However, my beginning state is same as my ending state. Is there any way I can execute the code without writing it before the loop?

```
for(int i = queue1->front; 
    i%queue1->size != queue1->front; 
    i++) {
    //some code
}
```

In the code, I am using a circular array and I want to print that using a loop.

Comment: I can make another iterator and make it equal to 0 in the beginning and add it to the conditional as || j == 0 maybe

Comment: You need to use a `do {} while` loop so that `i` is incremented before the loop condition is checked.

Comment: Yes i would be the index of the array

Comment: I thought of do while loops but I didn't thing they were looking elegant- I dunno maybe I'm so stupid lol.

Comment: Under current conditions the loop qouldnt execute but it will after the first step

Comment: It's certainly more elegant than copying the first iteration outside the for ;) (remember to ping users with @[username], otherwise they won't know who are you talking to)

Comment: If you make your example more concrete, it'll be easier to help you.

Comment: @A.Eser I agree that `do {} while` is ugly, but this is the type of problem it was meant to solve.  The other option is an infinite loop `for (;;)` where you put an `if` statement at the end of the loop, and `break` when the condition is met.

Comment: By *state*, you mean *conditional expression*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from using a do-while-loop you could use a flag to enter the loop in any case like this:

```
int first = 1;
for (int i = queue1->front; i%queue1->size != queue1->front || first; i++){
    first = 0;
    //some code
}
```

You can even integrate it directly into the for loop header, if you like:

```
for (int i = queue1->front, f=1; i%queue1->size != queue1->front || f; i++, f=0) {
```

Comment: This "flag" kind of solution is what I was looking for. Thanks for the new point of view!

Comment: I prefer using `bool` for flag variables like `first` instead of using `int`.

Comment: @DavidRTribble Fine, and I like Batman and my steak medium. Where's your point? Aside from that, there is no boolean primitive in C.

Comment: @Ctx - I've been using `stdbool.h` since 1999, and it works for me. Yeah, I know it's not primitive, but eveyone should know what you mean by `bool`. It's 2018.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use a do while loop. The case where you want a loop that executes an arbitrary amount of times, but at least one is the typical use case for this kind of loop.

```
int i = queue1->front;
do { 
    //some code
    i++
} while(i%queue1->size != queue1->front)
```

Another option is to make sure that the condition in the for loop is true the first time. There are different ways to do this. One way is to use a flag.

```
int flag = 1;
for( ... ; ... || flag; ... ) {
    flag = 0;
    ...
}
```

You could use a `goto`. I would not recommend it though.

```
goto label;
int i=queue1->front; // Init will be skipped
                     // using this method
for(...) {
    label:
    ...
}
```

If the reason that you don't want to write the code twice just is to avoid duplicated code, you could refactor it out to a function. Sure, you'll have to write the function name twice, but it may still be an improvement.

```
myFunction();
for(...) {
     myFunction();
}
```

Comment: It looked a bit terse at the start, maybe the DVer didn't come back yet to recheck. That's the risk when submitting premature... +1 from me, however

Comment: Maybe so. Well' we'll see if the poster checks back.